# вывести букву "A" с помощью звездочек "*"

Tags: python, символы

по задаче " Напишите программу, в которой с использованием операторов цикла и форматированных литералов, сиволом " * " в области вывода отображается буква 'A' "

я написал код:

```
n = 4
s = 4
print((n +1) * " ", "*")
for i in range(4):
        print(n * " ", "*", (s-n) * " ", "*")
        s += 1
        n -= 1
        if i == 3:
                print(n * " ", "*", (s-n) * "*", "*")
print(n * " ", "*", (s-n+1) * " ", "*")
```

но не могу правильно вывести эти символы на экран. получается криво. как можно исправить код?

[image: вывод]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так, например?

```
n = 4
s = 4
print((n + 2) * " ", "**")
for i in range(4):
    print((n + 1) * " ", "*", (s - n) * " ", "*")
    s += 1
    n -= 1
    if i == 3:
        print((n + 1) * " ", "*", (s - n) * "*", "*")
print(n * " ", "*", (s - n + 2) * " ", "*")
```

Вывод:

```
       **
      *  *
     *    *
    *      *
   *        *
  * ******** *
 *            *
```

Это же просто. Сдвиньте чуть-чуть верхнюю часть буквы и все.